# How to iterate through an API response and insert proper data to identical divs?

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to create a „weather app” which is supposed to look like this: https://pictr.com/image/05IPpQ

I created an html markup, which looks like this:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card__box card__box--blue" draggable="true" id="box1">

      <div class="card__box--icon"></div>
      <div class="card__box--city"></div>
      <div class="card__box--country"></div>
      <div class="card__box--weather"></div>
      <div class="card__box--temperature"></div>
      <div class="card__box--close">
        <i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="card__box card__box--orange" draggable="true" id="box2">

      <div class="card__box--icon"></div>
      <div class="card__box--city"></div>
      <div class="card__box--country"></div>
      <div class="card__box--weather"></div>
      <div class="card__box--temperature"></div>
      <div class="card__box--close">
        <i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="card__box card__box--grey" draggable="true" id="box3">

      <div class="card__box--icon"></div>
      <div class="card__box--city"></div>
      <div class="card__box--country"></div>
      <div class="card__box--weather"></div>
      <div class="card__box--temperature"></div>
      <div class="card__box--close">
        <i class="fa fa-window-close" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="card__box card__box--new" draggable="false" id="empty">
      <div class="card__box--add">
        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p class="card__paragraph paragraph--smallest paragraph--grey text-center">Add more widgets</p>
  </div>
```

I’m trying to make this actually work by the use of https://openweathermap.org.

This is an example of the APIs’ response which I’m getting: 
https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=524901,703448,2643743&units=metric&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

My problem is that I don’t know how to iterate through the response and fill all of my ‚boxes’ with proper data from the API. I want the first object from the list to fill the first box, etc. Here’s my code.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getWeather);

// These are hard coded ID's of the cities (only way to get data for multiple cities without a premium account)
const locations = ['524901', '703448', '2643743'];

const weather = new Weather();

function getWeather() {
  const ui = new UI();
  weather
    .getWeather()
    .then(response => ui.display(response.list))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

class Weather {
  constructor(locations) {
    this.apiKey = 'b5f8df2f8d10af0fda257b295738dcdd';
    this.locations = locations;
  }

  // Fetch data from API
  async getWeather() {
    const response = await fetch(

      `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=${locations}&units=metric&appid=${
        this.apiKey
      }`
    );

    const responseData = await response.json();

    return responseData;
  } 
}
```

The display function is currently hardcoded to get the first object from the list, which is something i’m trying to avoid, and is currently left as is, just so that the app ‚works’.

```
class UI {
  constructor() {
    this.city = document.querySelector('.card__box--city');
    this.country = document.querySelector('.card__box--country');
    this.weather = document.querySelector('.card__box--weather');
    this.temperature = document.querySelector('.card__box--temperature');
    this.icon = document.querySelector('.card__box--icon');
  }

  display(response) {
    this.city.textContent = response[0].name;
    this.country.textContent = response[0].sys.country;
    this.weather.textContent = response[0].weather[0].description;
    this.temperature.textContent =
      Math.ceil(response[0].main.temp) + String.fromCharCode(176);
    const iconCode = response[0].weather[0].icon;
    this.icon.style.backgroundImage = `url(http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${iconCode}.png)`;
  }
}
```

I suspect there might be a problem with the UI constructor.

Comment: I hope you have obfuscated your API key.